# Update MSRP trough SOAP call

Tags: magento-1.9, soap, msrp

I can't find any endpoint to update / change the MSRP of a product, am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $client = new SoapClient('http://yourmagentohost.com/index.php/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1');
    $session = $client->login('yourapiusername','yourapipassword');
    $_productId = $product->getId();
    $msrp = 100;
    $client->catalogProductUpdate($session, $_productId, array(
        'msrp' => $msrp,
        )
    );
?>
```